# Dynamic Class import from module

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I have to import a class from a module in a package. I am trying to make my program extendable without editing the source code by having apps in a directory. For Example, I have the following directory structure:

```
Project/
    apps/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
    main.py
```

In both `a.py` and `b.py`, there would be a class that I would like to import directly into `main.py` as though the class was in `main.py` all along. I don't know the names of these apps or the classes inside them. Is there a way to do this?

I have also googled around for an answer to no avail.

EDIT.
I forgot to explain that I needed the imports to be dynamic. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: What do you mean they need to be dynamic? Will you be conditionally importing things at runtime? Have you looked at and tried [importlib]( https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this with help from a friend. Thank you all for your suggestions.

```
import importlib.machinery
import os
for module in os.listdir(apps_dir)[2:]:
    temp = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(module, 'apps/' + module).load_module()
    globals().update(temp.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, in `main.py`

```
import apps.a
import apps.b

apps.a.MyClassA
apps.b.MyClassB
```

or alternatively you can also

```
from apps.a import MyClassA
from apps.b import MyClassB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the class in main's namespace, then (in main.py):

```
from .apps.a import ClassA
from .apps.b import ClassB
```

You'll need to put an `__init__.py` file in the `Project` directory as well.